# difference between carrom ball and doosra

Tags: cricket, spin

what is the difference between doosra and carrom ball bowled by a spin bowler in cricket.And which way the ball turns in carrom ball and doosra?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, many persons confused about ***Dosra and Carom ball*** ,both deliveries are deliver by the use of off-spine,and both of these deliveries looks like leg spin, turning from leg to offside. Usually a player can spot the carom ball very easily but picking doosra is hard, it requires a lot of experience/practice/effort and time .

***Carom ball:***
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrom_ball.

***Doosra:***
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doosra

video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BSgBOiG7eLc
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oi3CYNAfldc
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2IKWk76Anjk

Normally people get confused about doosra and carom ball, because both these deliveries are normally used by off-spinner and both of these deliveries looks like leg spin, turning from leg side to offside. Usually a player can spot the carom ball very easily but picking doosra is hard, it requires a lot of experience